# Cannot jump to file or location link in grep-mode or compile-mode

Tags: debugging, projectile, grep, compile-mode

I have recently installed emacs on a new system (*Manjaro arch-linux*), using my usual configuration (available [here](https://gist.github.com/pthalamy/e8002c8ac233a8292449084ed406eacf), if relevant).

However, the jump function never works on this new system: whenever I click a link to a location in a file in `grep-mode`, `compile-mode`, or any other mode using these links, I get an error which says `Symbol's function definition is void: orig-fun`.

For information I am mostly relying on `helm`, `projectile`, and `desktop-mode` in my workflow, if relevant.

I am using **emacs 26.1**, though I do not believe it is version-related, as I could replicate this problem on earlier versions of emacs (emacs 25 and 24).

I do not know how to further diagnose the issue or how to interpret this error, hence I would appreciate some suggestions.

EDIT1: This is the backtrace of the error, obtained through the emacs debugger (ran a `grep-find` with search term *"emacs"* on my `home` directory and selected the first link):

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function orig-fun)
  orig-fun(#<marker at 145 in *grep*> "./.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh" nil nil)
  compilation-find-file-projectile-find-compilation-buffer(#f(compiled-function (marker filename directory &rest formats) "Find a buffer for file FILENAME.\nIf FILENAME is not found at all, ask the user where to find it.\nPop up the buffer containing MARKER and scroll to MARKER if we ask\nthe user where to find the file.\nSearch the directories in `compilation-search-path'.\nA nil in `compilation-search-path' means to try the\n\"current\" directory, which is passed in DIRECTORY.\nIf DIRECTORY is relative, it is combined with `default-directory'.\nIf DIRECTORY is nil, that means use `default-directory'.\nFORMATS, if given, is a list of formats to reformat FILENAME when\nlooking for it: for each element FMT in FORMATS, this function\nattempts to find a file whose name is produced by (format FMT FILENAME)." #<bytecode 0x168f211>) #<marker at 145 in *grep*> "./.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh" nil)
  apply(compilation-find-file-projectile-find-compilation-buffer #f(compiled-function (marker filename directory &rest formats) "Find a buffer for file FILENAME.\nIf FILENAME is not found at all, ask the user where to find it.\nPop up the buffer containing MARKER and scroll to MARKER if we ask\nthe user where to find the file.\nSearch the directories in `compilation-search-path'.\nA nil in `compilation-search-path' means to try the\n\"current\" directory, which is passed in DIRECTORY.\nIf DIRECTORY is relative, it is combined with `default-directory'.\nIf DIRECTORY is nil, that means use `default-directory'.\nFORMATS, if given, is a list of formats to reformat FILENAME when\nlooking for it: for each element FMT in FORMATS, this function\nattempts to find a file whose name is produced by (format FMT FILENAME)." #<bytecode 0x168f211>) (#<marker at 145 in *grep*> "./.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh" nil))
  compilation-find-file(#<marker at 145 in *grep*> "./.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh" nil)
  apply(compilation-find-file #<marker at 145 in *grep*> "./.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh" nil nil)
  compilation-next-error-function(0 nil)
  next-error-internal()
  compile-goto-error(return)
  funcall-interactively(compile-goto-error return)
  call-interactively(compile-goto-error nil nil)
  command-execute(compile-goto-error)
```

Comment: Does it happen if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` and run `M-x package-initialize`? Switch on "'Enter Debugger on Error" in the "Options" menu. Add the backtrace which you get in the error case to your question.

Comment: Yes @Tobias, it does work when running `emacs -Q`, both before and after calling `M-x package-initialize`. However, after calling `load-file` on my `.emacs`, it stops working.

I have added an error backtrace to the question, as requested.

Comment: I think you should update projectile. See https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/1364 It is quite clear that https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/pull/1363/commits/ea3eb81dd6deee2ccae5f00cc867e7abdda7b085 fixes your problem.

Comment: FYI `orig-fun` is a name commonly used in advice written in the `nadvice` style, so I would initially suspect that some advice is playing up.

Comment: This is also a good reason not to just blindly install the latest versions of packages when you install your Emacs config on a new machine.  Keeping your entire config under version control ensures that it will be in a known and working state when you clone it.

Comment: If updating Projectile doesn't fix the problem, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: This was indeed a projectile version issue; updating to the latest version fixed the issue. @Tobias you can post your comment as an answer and I will mark the question as resolved. Thanks for the debugging guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of that error is a [fixed problem in Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/1364).

Avoid this problem by updating to a [Projectile version where this problem is fixed](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/pull/1363/commits/ea3eb81dd6deee2ccae5f00cc867e7abdda7b085).